# Calculating memory occupied by a ThreadGroup

Tags: java, multithreading, memory

I am writing application that is capable of running multiple instances of a Java game. Each instance of the game has multiple threads, which are grouped in a `ThreadGroup` object. I want to be able to detect the fact that another instance of the game could not be added because there will probably not be enough memory. The way that I plan to implement this is by averaging the amount of memory occupied by each `ThreadGroup`, and then determining if there is enough space available in memory with the aid of `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`. However, I can't find a programmatic way of calculating the amount of memory that a `ThreadGroup` (or even an individual thread) occupies.

I found profilers that are capable of displaying this information, but I need this solution to be programmatic.

Comment: This is impossible because the memory (except for the thread stacks) is shared by all threads and thus all thread groups. The JVM does not record a thread owner for each object.

Comment: Instrumentation much?

Comment: There is no SE standard API for this as creating and analyzing a heap dump is not supposed to be a standard runtime operation but more of a debugging operation.